# I have setup my DNN9 site to require an email address as a login name but now I cant login as Superuser anymore - Superuser login name is host

Tags: authentication, dotnetnuke

My Superuser account has a login name of host.  I have a few DNN9 websites that I log in to with no problems but on one of my sites I enabled 'Use Email Address as Username' so now I cant login anymore as obviously 'host' is not an email address, I have tried to login using the associated emil address but I get "A critical error has occurred. Please check the Event Viewer for further details."  I can still login to the other sites using 'host' so I think this setting change only applies to the one site.  How do I disable 'Use Email Address as Username' for the new site so I can login as host again without logging in as Superuser?  I do have server access so am able to edit files if this is the solution.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you describe it sounds like you have 1 DNN instance with multiple portals (Sites)?

If yes, you can login as host/superuser on any portal in the DNN instance and then go to Manage/Sites. Then go to the Settings of the Portal where 'Use Email Address as Username' is on and turn it off.

If it is not the same DNN instance, then...

If you have access to the database and know your PortalID, you can go in to the PortalSettings table and you are looking for SettingName = "Registration_UseEmailAsUserName"... just change it to False.

Then restart the site's app pool and try to login. Assuming it works, rename this "host" user so that the username and email are the same.

Then you should be able to go band and set 'Use Email Address as Username' again in the normal way.